# How to copy the Anaconda directory to another location and make it work?

Tags: python, anaconda

The situation is that, I'm using a server which can only access LAN, and I want to migrate an existing Anaconda environment to another directory. And the reason why I'm doing this is because there are so many required packages installed on that environment, and I really do not want to download and install those packages again :(

Since all the procedures are **without internet connection**, I cannot just simply use commands like `conda create --clone`, or export and import `.yml` files. Thus [these answers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine) are not helpful.

I tried copying the whole folder (recursively) directly to the new location. Although the symbolic links are migrated correctly, multiple files containing the location (writing at the first line inside these files) are not correct, such as in `bin/conda`:

```
#!/data/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python
```

where the path is incorrect.

I found some discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/TJBtuWab1DE), but still cannot figure out a way to solve the problem.

Comment: So edit the files and correct the broken shebang?

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a shot.
https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/
This should zip up your environment and then deploy it wherever you unpack it.

Comment: I believe that the OP said no internet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fair point, yeah it even says on the caveats that it isn't great for this application

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175427)

Comment: seems to work well in my case.